# Access MSBuild from Post Build Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, tfs

I'm using the default process template that comes with `TFS 2013` and I have a post build script that runs after the build is done. The script is a `Powershell` script that copies over some files required for me to generate an MSI. What I want to know is how to retrieve information about my build such as the `MSBuild Arguments` that I stated. I need to get the value that I set in the build definition. Is there a way that I can access this without writing functions that go on `TFS` and retrieve the build definition information?

Comment: Out if interest, what are you using to generate the MSI? IF you're using WiX you can add a wixproj to your solution. I believe that other packaging tools such as install shield also offer similar functionality. Then the MSI creation becomes part of your regular build process.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few of the TFS variables get defined as environment variables.  See these example scripts: https://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Scripts/GatherItemsForDrop.ps1   Here is the environment variable reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850448.aspx  While that doesn't contain an env var for MSBuild arguments, you can always pass the same arguments to your PowerShell script via the `post-build script arguments` process parameter.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to avoid this. Seeing as though this can be tricky, I've considered writing a function in a module, but it seems like a lot of work. I'll have to think of a different way around my problem. I'm just going to delete this question